# Android Gridview of Webviews: how avoid scrolling refresh

Tags: android, gridview, webview, refresh

I'm having a very annoying problem with a gridview of webviews in my application. I need to load an image from URL in each webview. The code seems to work quite well, but, when I scroll the gridview, the webviews always refresh giving an unpleasant effect. Moreover, if I scroll quickly and continuously, the gridview sometimes loses some cells (which become black) and then totally disappears. I tried to load images in a grid of imageviews but I was not able to display the imageviews at all.
This is my main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    dpResult = new DatePicker(this);

    thumbPaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
    mProgressDialog
            .setMessage("Loading..");

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    desiredDate = formatter.format(today);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    new ProgressTask().execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog.show();
        gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        thumbPaths.clear();

            if (checkConnection())
            {
                try {
                    thumbPaths = Thumbs.GetThumbs(desiredDate);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "No connection!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Gridview adapter

                adapter = new GridViewImageAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        thumbPaths);

                // setting grid view adapter
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}`
```

This is its layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rassegna_stampa1" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And, finally, this is the GridviewAdapter:

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> thumbPaths = new ArrayList<String>();

public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> thumbPaths) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this.thumbPaths = thumbPaths;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.thumbPaths.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.thumbPaths.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return this.thumbPaths.get(position).hashCode();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    WebView imView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imView = new WebView(_activity);
    } else {
        imView = (WebView) convertView;
    }


    imView.loadUrl(thumbPaths.get(position));
    return imView;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you read about? [setOnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) about onScroll and [onScrollStateChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html)

Comment: Since on scroll event nothing should happened, I tried to add an empty OnScrollListener to the GridView...but the problem persists